# Add feature to sort similar question suggestions by matching tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, asking-questions, similar-questions

**Feature**

On the 'Ask a question' pages, there should be a setting to the right of 'Questions that may already have your answer' that, when enabled (disabled by default), would sort the list based on the quantity of matching tags; this way, I would no longer get similar question suggestions that aren't even about the same programming language, when asking a question on SO.

**Feature-of-feature #1**

Underneath (or to the right of) each suggestion's title, there would be a list of their matching tags. If they have too many matches s.t. they can't fit inline, they will collapse to a single tag which states the number of matches.

**Feature-of-feature #2**

If I enabled the 'flutter' tag and enabled the aforementioned setting, then the first suggestions on the list would be the one(s) which contain the 'flutter' tag (if any), and after those, the list would continue to be sorted the normal way.

**Feature-of-feature #3**

If the user has yet to add any tags to their question, the setting could still be toggled, but it would have no effect on the list until some tags were added.